# Docusign production integrator key returning 0 login accounts

Tags: docusignapi

My integrator key was working fine in demo environment and I managed to shift the key to production successfully. (When I go to production admin console, the key is listed under APIs and Keys section)

The problem is when I try to create the apiClient object with the production properties, I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException since loginInfo.getLoginAccounts() collection is empty. I use the service integration code segment which has given in the ReadMe of Java sdk repository.

```
AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.login();

// parse first account ID (user might belong to multiple accounts) and baseUrl
String accountBaseUrl = loginInfo.getLoginAccounts().get(0).getBaseUrl();
String[] accountDomain = accountBaseUrl.split("/v2");`
```

Any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you share which endpoint you are hitting for logininformation API call? Try hitting below endpoint in Postman or any Rest Client, and see if you see any response returned in the call.   https://{{environmentValue}}/restapi/v2/login_information?api_password=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hitting below endpoint in Postman or any Rest Client, and see if you see any response returned in the call. `https://{{environmentValue}}/restapi/v2/login_information?ap‌​i_password=true`

`{{environmentValue}}` will be either www.docusign.net,or na2.docusign.net or na3.docusign.net, do you know on which DocuSign site your account exists? If its NA1 then you need to hit www.docusign.net, if NA2 then na2.docusign.net and na3.docusign.net for NA3 site

Comment: I tried with your environmentValues and for na3.docusign.net it worked. But I'm confused why docusign go live documentation doesn't say about this fact. It only says to change the baseUrl to "www.docusign.net". Please explain and thank you very much for your help.!

Comment: I assume Documentation was written when DocuSign had only one site which was NA1, then from that time till now few more sites are added and also per https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html,  DocuSign does not recommend to use Legacy Header Authentication which you are currently using in your code. Instead you should use OAUTH based authentication which is not dependent on the site, instead it is dependent on the account server endpoints.

Comment: I'm using the official docusign java sdk. In the repository they have given the code snippet for service integrations authentication. According to your comment I think the sdk also needs to be updated with the Docusign recommendations, since it's one of their official sdks. Anyway you saved my day. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Java SDK would have code to take care of AccessToken whilst calling DS APIs. But to generate AccessToken that implementation needs to be developed on your end using approach Service Integration Auth approach. There are many libraries available to generate JWT token, which is the main reason why DS Java SDK does not have that code.